# find + sed, filename output

Tags: unix, sed, find

I have directory: `D:/Temp`, where there are a lot of subfolders with text files. Each folder has "file.txt". In some file.txt files is a word - "pattern". I would like check how many pattern words there are, and also get the filepath to that file.txt:

```
find D:/Temp -type f -name "file.txt" -exec basename {} cat {}  \; | sed -n '/pattern/p' | wc -l
```

Output should be:

```
4
D:/Temp/abc1/file.txt
D:/Temp/abc2/file.txt
D:/Temp/abc3/file.txt
D:/Temp/abc4/file.txt
```

Or similar.

Comment: Do you need to know how many files contain the pattern, or how many times the pattern appears in each file, or how many times the pattern appears across all the files, or something else?  The `-exec basename {} cat {} \;` is wrong — that part is easy to diagnose; what you need instead isn't as obvious.  Superficially, you might want some variant of `-exec grep -c pattern {} +` (that would count the number of matching lines in each file, giving the file name and a count — including zeros).  It might be sufficient to use `-l` in place of `-c` if you want to know about the number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file names don't contain spaces then all you need is:

```
awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME; cnt++; nextfile} END{print cnt+0}' $(find D:/Temp -type f -name "file.txt")
```

The above used GNU awk for `nextfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GNU `grep` :

```
grep -lr --include file.txt "pattern" "D:/Temp/"
```

This will return the file paths.

```
grep -cr --include file.txt "pattern" "D:/Temp/"
```

This will return the count (counting the pattern occurences rather than the number of files)

Explanation of the flags :

- `-r` makes grep recursively browse its target, that can then be a directory
- `--include <glob>` makes grep restrict its recursive browsing to files matching the `<glob>`.
- `-l` makes grep only return the files path. Additionnaly, it will stop parsing a file as soon as it has encountered the pattern.
- `-c` makes grep only return the number of matches

Comment: I've mentionned GNU grep as I'm not sure all flags are POSIX specified, if someone can confirm or infirm it I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I'll add that in most scenarios, it may be moot -- the `grep` included in FreeBSD, NetBSD and OSX is based on GNU grep, and includes the options you've mentioned. Safe to say that OpenBSD, along with any SVR4 (Solaris, HP/UX) Unix would have a grep that does not include `--include`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose you to use two commands : one for find all the files:

```
find ./ -name "file.txt" -exec fgrep -l "-pattern" {} \;
```

Another for counting them:

```
find ./ -name "file.txt" -exec fgrep -l "-pattern" {} \; | wc -l
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that two commands can be combined using a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this safe and standard version:

```
find D:/Temp -type f -name file.txt -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "%s" "${@}"; grep -c "pattern" "${@}"' | grep ":[1-9][0-9]*$"
```

For each `file.txt` file found in `D:/Temp` directory and sub-directories, the `xargs` command prints the filename and the number of lines which contain `pattern` (`grep -c`).

A final `grep ":[1-9][0-9]*$"` selects only filenames with a count greater than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I've used:

```
grep -Hc "pattern" $(find D:/temp -type f -name "file.txt")
```

This will only work if file.txt is found. Otherwise you could use the following which will account for when both files are found or not found:

```
searchFiles=$(find D:/temp -type f -name "file.txt"); [[ ! -z "$searchFiles" ]] && grep -Hc "pattern" $searchFiles
```

The output for this would look more like:

```
D:/Temp/abc1/file.txt 2
D:/Temp/abc2/file.txt 1
D:/Temp/abc3/file.txt 1
D:/Temp/abc4/file.txt 1
```

Comment: As an alternative in the same spirit, you could use `xargs` to use the result of `find` as `grep`'s arguments. This could solve the error when no "file.txt" is found if using `xargs`'s `-r` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
find D:/Temp -type f -name "file.txt" -exec dirname {} \; > tmpfile
wc -l tmpfile
cat tmpfile
rm tmpfile
```

Comment: Instead of running a separate `dirname` process for each and every file, it would probably be more performant simply to print the output and post-process it with `sed 's:/[^/]*$::'` to strip off the filenames. If the post-processing were done with awk, you could also eliminate the tmpfile easily enough.

Comment: @ghoti Actually a single awk solution should be the best. My one is dirty and simple. Probably too dirty ;)

Comment: I hesitated to suggest awk because the start-directory format suggested the OP is using Windows, where awk is not native. I suppose your solution is appropriate, given the platform on which this solution will be implemented!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm reading your question, I'm going to answer as if:

- some but not all `file.txt` files contain `pattern`,
- you want a list of the paths leading to file.txt with `pattern`, and
- you want a count of `pattern` in each of those files.

There are a few options.  (Always multiple ways to do anything.)

If your bash is version 4 or higher, you can use `globstar` to recurse through directories:

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/file.txt; do
  if count=$(grep -c 'pattern' "$file"); then
    printf "%d %s\n" "$count" "${file%/*}"
  fi
done
```

This works because the `if` evaluation considers a failed `grep` (i.e. zero occurrences) to be FALSE, and thus does not print results.

Note that this may be high impact because it launches a separate `grep` on each file that is found.  A lighter weight alternative might be to run a single grep on the fileglob, and parse the results:

```
shopt -s globstar

grep -c 'pattern' **/file.txt | grep -v ':0$'
```

This also depends on bash 4, and of course if you have millions of files you may overwhelm bash's command line maximum length.  The output of this will be obvious, but you'll need to parse it with care if your filenames contain colons.  I.e. `cut -d: -f2` may not cut it.

One more option that leverages grep instead of bash might be:

```
grep -r --include 'file.txt' -c 'pattern' ./ | grep -v ':0$'
```

This uses GNU grep's `--include` option which modified the behaviour of `-r` (recursive).  It should work in Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OSX, but not with the default grep on OpenBSD or most SVR4 (Solaris, HP/UX, etc).

Note that I have tested none of these. No liability assumed.  May contain nuts.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
find . -name "file.txt" -type f -printf '%p\n' | awk '{print} END { print NR }'
```

Comment: And why look to "config" instead of "file.txt"?

Comment: Probably this is not answer for my question. I would like find those file.txt which contains word "pattern", not all file.txt.